# Php user session not being set

Tags: php, session, authentication

Boy am I confused. So I had a working login system when I was working a different database name. I changed over all the names  and files to fit the new sql database. Everything seems to work except that my login check says that I am not logged in. It seems to be a problem that the session is not set.

I first have a login page that sends you through this page successfully (I end up at member_home):

```
<?php
include_once './../functions.php';
include_once './../dbConnect.php';

sec_session_start(); // custom way of starting a PHP session.



if (isset($_POST['user'], $_POST['p'])) {
    $user = $_POST['user'];
    $password = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'p', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    if (strlen($password) != 128) {
        // The hashed pwd should be 128 characters long.
        // If it's not, something really odd has happened
        echo 'hashed password length wrong';
    }
    //$password = $_POST['p']; // The hashed password.

    if (login($user, $password, $dbConnection) == true) {
        // Login success 
        $con = @require './../dbConnect.php';
        // Check connection
        if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
          {
          echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
          }
        else {
        $result = mysqli_query($dbConnection,"SELECT * FROM members WHERE user = '". $_SESSION['user'] ."'");
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        $passkey1 = $row['confirmcode'];
        header('Location: http://www.examplewebsite.com/member_home.php?passkey='.$passkey1);
    }
    }
    else {
        // Login failed 
        header('Location: ../login_page.php?error=1');
        echo 'login failed';
    }
} else {
    // The correct POST variables were not sent to this page. 
    echo 'Invalid Request';
}
?>
```

On my member home page it requires that the user is logged in via this function login_check:

```
function login_check($dbConnection) {
    // Check if all session variables are set 
    //this session is not being set....
    if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'], 
                        $_SESSION['user'], 
                        $_SESSION['login_string'])) {
                        header('Location: http://www.examplewebsite.com/index.php');

        $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
        $login_string = $_SESSION['login_string'];
        $username = $_SESSION['user'];

        // Get the user-agent string of the user.
        $user_browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

        if ($stmt = $dbConnection->prepare("SELECT password 
                                      FROM members 
                                      WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1")) {
            // Bind "$user_id" to parameter. 
            $stmt->bind_param('i', $user_id);
            $stmt->execute();   // Execute the prepared query.
            $stmt->store_result();

            if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
                //we are not making it to this if statement
                // If the user exists get variables from result.
                $stmt->bind_result($password);
                $stmt->fetch();
                $login_check = hash('sha512', $password . $user_browser);

                if ($login_check == $login_string) {
                    // Logged In!!!! 
                    return true;
                } else {
                    // Not logged in 
                    return false;
                }
            } else {
                // Not logged in 
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            // Not logged in 
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        // Not logged in 
        return false;
    }
}
```

I know I don't pass the first if statement because I was not relocated via the header check.

Here is the sec_session_start() function and I've tested and seen that it does indeed go through this entire function:

```
function sec_session_start() {

    $session_name = 'sec_session_id';   // Set a custom session name
    $secure = SECURE;
    // This stops JavaScript being able to access the session id.
    $httponly = true;
    // Forces sessions to only use cookies.
    if (ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1) === FALSE) {
        header("Location: ../error.php?err=Could not initiate a safe session (ini_set)");
        exit();
    }
    // Gets current cookies params.
    $cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params();
    session_set_cookie_params($cookieParams["lifetime"],
        $cookieParams["path"], 
        $cookieParams["domain"], 
        $secure,
        $httponly);
    // Sets the session name to the one set above.
    session_name($session_name);
    session_start();            // Start the PHP session 
    session_regenerate_id();    // regenerated the session, delete the old one. 
}
```

So for some reason, my loginCheck function always fails and I can't figure out why the session is not set! Is something wrong here or would it be elsewhere? Can someone lead me in a direction to check for other errors?

The problem only started occurring after switching all the databasenames and related, but I can't find anywhere where the text is different.

Here is my login variable, responsible for binding everything:

```
function login($user, $password, $dbConnection) {
    global $errors;
    $errors = 1;
    // Using prepared statements means that SQL injection is not possible. 
    if ($stmt = $dbConnection->prepare("SELECT ID, user, paid, password, salt 
        FROM members WHERE user = ? LIMIT 1")) {
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $user);  // Bind "$user" to parameter.
        $stmt->execute();    // Execute the prepared query.
        $stmt->store_result();

        // get variables from result.
        $stmt->bind_result($user_id, $user, $paid, $db_password, $salt);
        $stmt->fetch();

        // hash the password with the unique salt.
        $password = hash('sha512', $password . $salt);
        $errors= 2;
        if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {

                if ($db_password == $password) {
                    // Password is correct!
                    // Get the user-agent string of the user.
                    $user_browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
                    // XSS protection as we might print this value
                    $user_id = preg_replace("/[^0-9]+/", "", $user_id);
                    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
                    // XSS protection as we might print this value
                    $user = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+/", 
                                                                "", 
                                                                $user);
                    $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
                    $_SESSION['login_string'] = hash('sha512', 
                              $password . $user_browser);
                    // Login successful.
                    $errors=3;
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        else {
            // No user exists.
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I actually CAN'T get the $errors variable to post in member_home neither.

I mean again, the problem seems to be that after I send the user to member_home, there is no longer a defined $_SESSION['user']. It just seems to all disappear after the header(location:member_home)

Comment: did you populate the name/password values to a new table?
Are you using MD5 for the passwords? And did you just copy the old values to the new table?
Test by setting a new user name and password in the new table.

Comment: I have a registration form, and created a new user in the new table via that. Using a hash for the passwords -- all detail checks (and hence taking from sql) are all passing. Everything is working except the session doesn't seem to be setting anymore-- just don't know why because it's all the same code...

Comment: If you go back to the old database name - does it work again?

Comment: What error or result are you getting? how do you know the session has failed?

Comment: all i know is that where the problem is occurring is in function login_check and the first if statement is not being executed. The  if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'], 
                        $_SESSION['user'], which then leads to the else statement to return false for the function which restricts access to my home page.

Comment: And have you located the bug? I mean where it fails? Was it switching only database names or something more? Like for example switching server. I would suggest you to test setting up session on the simple page. Just start session and do all the stuff with session you are trying to do in your code on the simple php page. And debug and look at output.

Comment: What are the values of "$_SESSION['user_id'], 
                        $_SESSION['user'], 
                        $_SESSION['login_string'])) " in the else - try echoing them

Comment: @user1066035 do var_dump($_POST); and see if your post variables are even set...

Comment: Both the session and post variables are now gone -- or at least I can't echo them on the member_home page. They seem to disappear after I move the user using the header('Location: http://www.examplewebsite.com/member_home.php?passkey='.$passkey1); in the first function. I'll add the login function which binds the variables